# new to Batch script, what exactly this for loop do

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bactch script which I am trying to understand, as I am new to batch programming and have to customize this code. but I can't understand what the subroutines check_utf8_bom,create_utf8bom_free_file,remove_utf8 are actually doing. Can someone please help

```
 set /p bom=<.\bom    
    for /f "delims=" %%G in (.\file-list.txt) do (
           call:check_utf8_bom %bom% !SOURCE_FOLDER!
        )

    :check_utf8_bom
        rem ;; Checks If There Is The UTF-8 Bom At The Beginning Of The File
        set /p firstLine=<%2\tmp

        if "%firstLine:~0,3%"=="%~1" call:create_utf8bom_free_file %2
        goto:eof    

:create_utf8bom_free_file
    rem ;; Remove UTF-8 BOM From "tmp" File o Avoid Problems During Interpretation
    type %1\tmp>%1\tmp.bom

    for /f "delims=" %%G in (%1\tmp.bom) do (
        if defined i echo.%%G>>%1\tmp
        if not defined i (
            call:remove_utf8_bom  "%%G" %1
            set i=1
        )
    )
    del %1\tmp.bom
    goto:eof

:remove_utf8_bom
    rem ;; Called From create_utf8bom_free_file Function Create The File Without The BOM In The First line
    set fl=%~1
    echo %fl:~3,-1%%fl:~-1%>"%2\tmp"
    goto:eof
```

can somebody please help me to understand it?

Comment: i think including **tmp.bom** (or at least a sample of it's content) is very needed

Comment: You are only showing us part of the code from the script you copied it from.  Where did you get his code. Please provide a link to where you found it.

Comment: @user3733648, please elaborate what would you like to modify in this code in order to make it possible to provide you with a targeted explanation which, supposedly, would be much more easier to understand and *use*.

Comment: BTW here's my take on detecting and stripping the BOM: http://pastie.org/private/6g29u7ynyxvzzrcyjshfmg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%1` stands for the first argument passed to the script / `:create_utf8bom_free_file` subroutine.

`type %1\tmp>%1\tmp.bom` this [prints](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) file `tmp` from `%1` directory to `tmp.bom` file - this should convert unicode file to ascii one (probaly without changing [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) )

`for /f "delims=" %%G in (%1\tmp.bom) do`  - means read `%1\tmp.bom` [line by line](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)  without splitting the line with delimiters (`"delims="`) so on each iteration the line will be assigned to `%%G` token (temporary variable that lives during  `FOR /F` execution).

`if not defined i` and  `set i=1` is a workaround for missing break operator in batch file loops . [The first checks](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) if the variable is defined and the second sets value to the variable. So the first line is passed to `:remove_utf8_bom` (here the first two characters of the line should be removed) function and then the for loop is over.

At the end temp file is deleted and `goto:eof` means go to the end of the script - i.e. something similar to exit.

Comment: Sorry the question was edited after the answer arrived.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what the script does because you didn't post the remove_utf8_bom procedure. So far I can tell you that the the loop reads the content of the file tmp.bom line by line. In each iteration it checks whether the variable i is set or not. If it is, the currently processed line is appended to the file tmp. Otherwise the current line as well as the parameter %1 both are passed to the procedure remove_utf8_bom (which we don't know) and the variable i is being set to 1.

This is - as you've asked - what the for-loop does (without the lines above and below it). For more information I need more code.

**EDIT:**

By the way...even without the code I'd suppose that this script should remove the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded text files. This is often needed because if a batch or cmd file is stored in UTF-8 there is a BOM at the beginning of it which causes that the first line in the script won't be executed.

To eliminate this problem you should avoid saving scripts as UTF-8. If you can't be sure about the encoding, you also could start scripts with `REM doesn't matter what text is here` as this line will be ignored. The rest of the script will be executed as desired.

Comment: Sorry the question was edited after the answer arrived.